# How can I add a "universal" GRUB?

Tags: grub2

I have ubuntu in a windows PC. Recently I added Android to the computer and it does install another grub. The problem is: The Android-x86 GRUB, don't show-me Ubuntu, and the Ubuntu Grub don't show-me Android-x86. What I can do?

Answer (score 1):

From Ubuntu, open a Terminal and try:

```
sudo update-grub
```

And reboot.. Did your additional OS get added to the Grub list?

Comment: OK! Keep me posted :)